# Calling a generic method with a generic parameter doesn't work without cast

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

First of all, sorry for the title but even after minutes of thinking, this was best I found. Here the situation:

I have an abstract 'Factory' class. It takes T as return type of the instance.

```
abstract class Factory<T> {
    abstract T getInstance();
}
```

Now I add an interface to mark classes which have a factory. This interface is parameterized with the Factory itself.

```
interface Factorized<TFACTORY extends Factory<?>> {}
```

Now I can mark classes that have a factory.

```
class BaseImpl1 implements Factorized<BaseImpl1Factory> {}
class BaseImpl1Factory extends Factory<BaseImpl1> {
    @Override BaseImpl1 getInstance() { return null; /* TODO */}
}
```

With a small method and some reflection I can get an instance of the factory by passing the base class itself.

```
<RETURNED_FACTORY extends Factory<?>> RETURNED_FACTORY getFactory(Class<? extends Factorized<RETURNED_FACTORY>> clazz) {
    /* TODO */
}

// usage:
BaseImpl1Factory factory = getFactory(BaseImpl1.class);
```

This works fine until the point where I **add generics in the base class**.

See the full example:

```
public class Test {
    void test() {
        getFactory(BaseImpl1.class).someMethod1();
        getFactory(BaseImpl2.class).someMethod2();     // <-- compile error
        getFactory((Class<? extends Factorized<BaseImpl2Factory>>) BaseImpl2.class).someMethod2(); // <-- it works with cast
        getFactory(SubBase2Impl.class).someMethod2();  // only for info.. this works
    }

    <RETURNED_FACTORY extends Factory<?>> RETURNED_FACTORY getFactory(Class<? extends Factorized<RETURNED_FACTORY>> clazz) {
         /* TODO */
    }
}

abstract class Factory<T> {
    abstract T getInstance();
}
interface Factorized<TFACTORY extends Factory<?>> {}

// ****** implementation without generic *******
class BaseImpl1 implements Factorized<BaseImpl1Factory> {}
class BaseImpl1Factory extends Factory<BaseImpl1> {
    void someMethod1(){}
    @Override BaseImpl1 getInstance() { /* TODO */ }
}

// ****** implementation with generic *******
class BaseImpl2<T> implements Factorized<BaseImpl2Factory> {}
class BaseImpl2Factory extends Factory<BaseImpl2<?>> {
    void someMethod2(){}
    @Override BaseImpl2<?> getInstance() { /* TODO */ }
}

class SubBase2Impl extends BaseImpl2<String>{}
```

It works when I cast it but why do I have to? What do I have to change to access the factory without casting?

Hints:

- It is required to get the concrete instance BaseImpl1Factory and not only the abstract Factory instance when calling getFactory() because the factories have diffent methods and it should be needed to cast
- Please don't care about the probably stupid plan behind this. Actually the real problem is completely different but wanted to take out the business problem as much as possible

Comment: Why is it `?` in `extends Factory<?>`? It seems like you'd want to be able to specify what kind of factory this thing is, in which case you'd want to use a second type parameter instead of `?`: `interface Factorized<T, TFACTORY extends Factory<T>>`.

Comment: I understand this idea but I don't think that this would solve my problem?! This would be the next step to wire the classes and the factories together. Or can you provide a full example?

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for what's called a [self-type](http://blog.joda.org/2007/08/java-7-self-types_1953.html). Here's an example:

```
interface Factory<T> { T getInstance(); }

interface Buildable<T> { Factory<T> getFactory(); }

class CanBuild implements Buildable<CanBuild> {
  @Override
  public Factory<CanBuild> getFactory() {
    return null; // TODO
  }
}
```

The `Buildable` interface (`Factorized` in your example) indicates a type that can build `T`s. While `T` could be any type, you'll often use it as a self-type by making `T` the same type as the class being defined.

Self-types are commonly used when defining [fluent interfaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluent_interface). The [Truth](https://github.com/google/truth) library uses them heavily, so you might like to poke around their code to see more examples.